# Task.whenall vs Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() on very task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Have I have created `Task` using:

`Task.Factory.StartNew<GroupPreferenceList>(())`

And Calling a function, like that i have 7 methods all the methods contain one or two API call. Now I am using :
`Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on very task to get the Result of very task and do some manipulation on it. 
My question is whether I should create another and Use `WhenAll()` or what I am doing is correct and faster.

Thanks

Comment: Please post code. It's a bit vague just upon that description.

Comment: Only if you want to wait until all of them are ready you have to use WhenAll()

Comment: Well, for one thing `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult` is a blocking call and can lead to deadlocks. So use `await`. Second, if the tasks can run parallel use `WhenAll`, otherwise they will wait for each other to complete in a sequential order.

Comment: #Peter Bons, as the Task is created by using Factory.start() then at that time the function get executed, That's why I am not using WhenAll(), please suggest if am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of points in this regard:

- Instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew<GroupPreferenceList>(())` use `Task.Run<GroupPreferenceList>(())`, here's the nice information by Stephen Cleary [StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)
- Beyond this why do you need `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` at all, I can understand using `GetAwaiter()` on a awaited Task, but this has no use case here. Also each of the call will be on Main thread, thus taking away the benefits of concurrency and waiting to fetch each executed Task result
- You use `WhenAll()`, when you want to get single representative Task for all the collection of tasks and await it

In this case my suggestion is:

- Simply create a collection of Task using `Task.Run` for each one of them
- Do `Task.WaitAll` to wait each of them to complete, then access the Result for each `Result` call for the Task object, provided you are using the Generic version as base class of `Task` doesn't have it.

Answer above is based on the premise that you need TPL for processing, in case its IO based concurrency, then convert complete call into Async-Await, since that's best suited for the IO based concurrency

Comment: Hi, Mrinal, Have tried your suggestion by using **Task.Run** and **waitAll**and then harvesting the result of the each task by .Result but on the performance it does not have any impact.

Comment: @SantoshJha You have probably misunderstood my point, since that depends totally on amount of data / records you are processing, whether TPL will provide benefit for the in memory processing. Under the assumption that you have enough data to process, I was providing the right usage of the Task APIs. You may update question with some source code and data details, in case its few methods, it would be better to call W/o TPL

Comment: actually my Action takes 15 to 20 sec to get executed and in that there are 7 Web Api call and every service gets all most 30 to 50 records have more than 20 columns. That's why I thought to implement Task so That i can save the call time of service. but it still taking little less time. **so is there any way to calculate the time of taken by task to create. so that we can assume that whether the TPL will be benefited**.

Comment: @SantoshJha as it seems you have number of Web API calls, data is not much though. Task Parallel library is not a good choice here, you need to convert the complete system into Async Await calls, as these are IO calls, meant for your use case.
Time of the Task can be measured using simple stop watch, that's not much of an issue, but here design as such is flawed

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Can you please send some link to understand the difference of TPL and Async await pattern, as per my understanding using Task to call a synchronous method on different thread and doing some other  action on main thread will save time. As I am new to TPL, and for using async await pattern I need to change all the functions with API call to async and returning the  Task.fromresult.  so I thought to implement Task. And another thing My action is returning  a partial view so won't be able to make the action async . Hope have stated my problem and thought.